# Drawing a checkered flag to the turtle screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

**QUESTION:** Implement the following pseudo-code to draw a checkered flag to the screen.

```
1.  Ask the user for the size of the checkered flag (n).
2.  Draw an n x n grid to the screen.
3.  For i = 0,2,4,...,62:
4.     row = i // n
5.     offset = row % 2
6.     col = (i % n) + offset
```

Please copy and paste the link see the [output](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/45977/12eaef67de44c2b291ecd47fe8d10135):

**I implemented the pseudocode, but I need some help. I can able to draw the n*n grid; moreover, I am keep getting this error: `NameError: name 'row' is not defined`**

My program:

```
from turtle import*

def size():
  size = eval(input("Please enter the size of the checkered flag: "))
  return size

def draw(n):
  wn = Screen()
  wn.setworldcoordinates(-1,-1,10,10)
  pen = Turtle()
  for i in range(0,n+1):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(0,i)
    pen.down()
    pen.forward(n)

  pen.left(90)
  for i in range(0,n+1):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(i,0)
    pen.down()
    pen.forward(n)

def findGrid(n):
  for i in range(0,63):
    row = i // n
    offset = row % 2
    col = (i % n) + offset

  return row, col

def fillSquare(x,y):
  pen = Turtle()
  pen.hideturtle()
  pen.speed(10)
  pen.up()
  pen.goto(x,y)
  pen.fillcolor("black")
  pen.begin_fill()

def main():
  x = size()
  y = draw(x)
  row, col = findGrid(x)             #I think the problem is here.
  f = fillSquare(row, col)

main()
```

Comment: Did I answer this question to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted in your question doesn't draw squares because you don't have any turtle operations after `pen.begin_fill()`.

You can draw a filled square like so:

```
  turtle.begin_fill()
  for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.right(90)
  turtle.end_fill()
```

There's actually a mistake in the pseudocode. The offset calculation `offset = row % 2` is only valid when `n`, the number of rows, is an even number. The pseudocode fails to calculate checkered square locations when `n` is odd.

To make the code work for even and odd values of `n`, you can evaluate the offset as follows:

```
    offset = ~(n % 2) & (row % 2)
```

I have implemented these changes in the code below. I have also modified the structure of your program by defining the turtle outside the drawing functions and passing it in as an argument. This lets us set the turtle's speed and visibility settings just once instead of having to do so within each drawing function.

```
from turtle import*

# Ask the user for the size of the checkered flag (n).
def getSize():
  size = eval(input('Please enter the size of the checkered flag: '))
  return size

# Draw an n x n grid to the screen.
def drawGrid(turtle, n):
  for i in range(0, n+1):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(0, i)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(n)
  turtle.left(90)
  for i in range(0, n+1):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(i, 0)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(n)

# Fill the square in the given row and column.
def fillSquare(turtle, row, col):
  turtle.up()
  turtle.goto(col, row)
  turtle.begin_fill()
  for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.right(90)
  turtle.end_fill()

def main():
  # Get the user's input.
  n = getSize()

  # Set up the drawing coordinates.
  screen = Screen()
  screen.setworldcoordinates(-1, -1, 10, 10)

  # Make a turtle object for use in drawing. Maximize its speed.
  turtle = Turtle()        
  turtle.speed('fastest')
  turtle.hideturtle()      

  # Draw the checkered flag.
  drawGrid(turtle, n)
  for i in range(0, n*n, 2):
    row = i // n
    offset = ~(n % 2) & (row % 2)
    col = i % n + offset
    fillSquare(turtle, row, col)

  print('Hit Enter to quit.')
  input()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where I believe *stamping* makes things simpler than *drawing* in Python turtle:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def getSize():
    """ Ask user for the size of the checkered flag. """

    return int(input('Please enter the size of the checkered flag: '))

cells = getSize()

screen = Screen()

size = min(screen.window_width() - 10, screen.window_height() - 30) / cells
offset = (cells % 2) * size/2 + size/2  # properly center odd & even cells

turtle = Turtle('square', visible=False)
turtle.shapesize(size / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.color('black')
turtle.penup()

for row in range(-cells // 2, cells // 2):
    parity = row % 2  # properly color cells
    turtle.goto(-cells // 2 * size + offset, row * size + offset)

    for column in range(cells):
        turtle.fillcolor(['white', 'black'][parity == column % 2])
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.forward(size)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Stamping also makes the program faster as we're working with larger chunks of the drawing.